# Elixir: How to seed a map?

Tags: elixir

I want to generate a map in Elixir along the lines of:

```
  [1: 1, 1: 2, 1: 3, 2: 1, ..... , 3: 3]
```

Here's the code:

```
  n = 3
  map = %{ 0, 0}
  for x <- 1..n do
    for y <- 1..n do
      map = %{map | x, y}
    end
  end
```

This code compiles but only has the original (0: 0) entry when run? How do I append to the map successfully with the recursive numbers and how do I seed the map at the outset. I tried map = nil but as it had no structure Elixir didn't like it.

Comment: That's not the map syntax and a map can't have duplicate keys. What's the exact value you're expecting?

Comment: They're not duplicate, or rather what I am trying to create is 
1,1 1,2 1,3 2,1...

Comment: The key `1` can't map to more than one value. You're associating it with 3 values. Can you post the exact map you want in Elixir syntax?

Comment: You really need to share what you're trying to get here because what you're asking right now simply can't be done.  Vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what you want as output I see two possible solutions:

1. Use a [`map`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html) with values as lists
2. Use a [`keyword`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html)

In the first case I would do something like this:

```
iex> start = 1             
1
iex> stop = 3
3
iex> Enum.reduce(start..stop, %{}, fn x, acc ->
...>   val = Enum.to_list(start..stop)         
...>   Map.put(acc, x, val)                    
...> end)
%{1 => [1, 2, 3], 2 => [1, 2, 3], 3 => [1, 2, 3]}
```

In the second case this (despite being a bit odd) may do the trick:

```
iex> f = fn(start, stop) -> 
...>   (start..stop)
...>   |> Enum.map(fn x ->
...>     Enum.map(start..stop, fn y -> {String.to_atom("#{x}"), y} end)
...>   end)
...>   |> Enum.flat_map(&(&1))
...> end
iex>
iex> f.(1, 3)
["1": 1, "1": 2, "1": 3, "2": 1, "2": 2, "2": 3, "3": 1, "3": 2, "3": 3]
```

Edit: A work colleague pointed out a simpler way of building the above keyword:

```
iex> {start, stop} = {1, 3}
{1, 3}
iex> l = for(x <- (start..stop), y <- (start..stop)) do
...>   {String.to_atom("#{x}"), y}
...> end
["1": 1, "1": 2, "1": 3, "2": 1, "2": 2, "2": 3, "3": 1, "3": 2, "3": 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your questions have so many problems.

1. `map = %{ 0, 0}` is not a correct map syntax
2. Elixir 's data is immutable and have scope. The map inside `for` can not affect outside map.
3. Elixir's map is hash map and can only match one key one value.